# \index command adds a space after command sequences, when used in \footnote

Tags: indexing

\index{Borel $\sigma$-algebra} behaves differently in a \footnote:

In main text it writes (to the .idx file)
\indexentry{Borel $\sigma$-algebra}{1}

When in a \footnote it writes
\indexentry{Borel $\sigma $-algebra}{1}

Note the extra space.  This results in separate index entries.

I can fix it by writing
\index{Borel $\string\sigma$-algebra}
when in a \footnote, but this seems like a kludge.

Is there a better way?